# styled components change style based on class without props

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I am using **Antd** and **Styledcomponents** in my ***react*** project.
I have a set of checkboxes and I want to change the style of **checked** checkboxes. Is there any way I can do this without passing props? just by giving the class name?

```
const StyledCheckBox = styled(Checkbox)`
 width: 90%;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 .ant-checkbox-wrapper-checked{
   background: #bee7ff;
 }`
```

Tried the above code and it doesn't work. Am I missing something or am I doing it wrong? Can someone explain how to solve this? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written it the `.ant-checkbox-wrapper-checked{}` style will be applied to an element **inside** your `StyledCheckBox`. If it should be the same element, you should write it like this (notice the `&`):

```
const StyledCheckBox = styled(Checkbox)`
 width: 90%;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 &.ant-checkbox-wrapper-checked{
   background: #bee7ff;
 }`
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know about the difference. It works now.